# Issue with "non-planar" edge loop

Tags: topology

I am in the process of modeling the refit USS Enterprise. I have reached an impasse at the bridge area. It's difficult to explain, but essentially I have an edge loop that needs to be filled in and it's not planar, if that makes sense. I'm not sure what the nomenclature for that is.  Anyways, I tried using grid fill to no avail so I decided to fill it in manually. I feel like my topology could be better though, and would be grateful for any feedback.

[image: wireframe]

[image: editmode]

[image: view1]

[image: descriptive]

Comment: Hello and welcome to the site! I honestly struggle to understand the current shape of your mesh. In addition to the two side views, can you also attach a view not parallel to any axis?

Comment: I have attached two more images

Comment: Thanks. I'm not a skilled hard surface modeller so I won't attempt to answer your question, but the added information might help other users.